# Popover Doesn't Work on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, uipopover

I implemented a `Popover` in my application and tested it. It will work fine on iPad but when I test it on iPhone, instead of showing `Popover` it will show the full storyboard. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func MenuIsClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    var moveToNextVC:MenuViewController

    moveToNextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuViewController") as! MenuViewController
    moveToNextVC.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    moveToNextVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200)

    if let popoverController = moveToNextVC.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverController.sourceView = sender as! UIView
        popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 85, height: 30)
        popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
        popoverController.delegate = self

    }
    presentViewController(moveToNextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController!, traitCollection: UITraitCollection!) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .None
}
```

**Edit:** As Popover is not work on iPhone but when a refer this [EthanStrider/iOS-Projects](https://github.com/EthanStrider/iOS-Projects) it will work fine. How?

Comment: A UIPopoverController is meant for use only on iPad devices.

Comment: `UIPopOver` are for IPAD only they don't work on IPhone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UIPopoverController's](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/index.html) are only available on iPad.

> Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices.
>   Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception.

Though with iOS 8+, it no longer crashes, it will be executed as full screen modal presentation..

Comment: but when a refer this https://github.com/EthanStrider/iOS-Projects it will work fine for iphone why?

Comment: Did you try it? The screenshot they include is for the iPhone and it looks pretty modal to me.

Comment: yes i will try it in my previous  application  work fine

Answer (score 0):

A UIPopoverController is meant for use only on iPad devices. You can refer to the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) to verify.

If you really want a popover on iPhone, you can use a third-party control like [WYPopoverController](https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this control else.

https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover/

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the `.none` parameter in this delegate method. When I added `UIModalPresentationStyle` in front of it - it started to work!

```
// Override the iPhone behavior that presents a popover as fullscreen
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
}
```

The reason was that I had another `.none` case defined in an enum in my project with another underlying Int value (which is of course bad practice, so please avoid that to begin with).